# Best way for building objects out of XMLs at runtime

Tags: java, actionscript-3, actionscript, jaxb

I'm in a situation that I have a lot of of XMLs, that are sent to me from a server and I'm using JAXB or any API based on that architecture for building instances of objects.

The problem is, I have to per-determine the class that I want to unmarshall for at compile time. My solution that is in my mind, is to read the incoming XML object and based on some tags, I will direct the unmrashaller to make an instance of the specified class. That approach will let me have a lot of IFs statements and big state machine.

Is there a better design pattern or approach ?

Comment: Do your xml files have associated schemas? My guess is that these help immensely for just this sort of thing.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yes they have. I'm also using AS3, in an application, and also JAVA for another application, and I need for both of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [Apache digester 3](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-digester/), I think it can save you lots of "if"s and is not difficult to use at all.

Have a look at this article: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-10-2002/jw-1025-opensourceprofile.html